# Redhat OpenShift - Connection refused fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: linux, ssh, proxy, git, openshift-online-2

I'm trying to start using **Redhat OpenShift** with a **JBoss 7** Server Cartridge, but as I'm trying to do a **git clone** I get:

```
$ git clone ssh://username_from_openshift@application_name-host_name.rhcloud.com/~/git/application_name.git/ /development/repos/openshift/
Initialized empty Git repository in /development/repos/openshift/.git/
ssh: connect to host application_name-host_name.rhcloud.com port 22: Connection refused
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Now I am doing this in a company and I am using it's proxy to access the internet on this machine. I'm running **Linux CentOS release 6.5 (Final)**.

I tried adding a **"config" file** with the following contents in ~/.ssh/:

```
Host application_name-host_name.rhcloud.com
ProxyCommand nc -X connect -x my_company_proxy.com:8080 %h %p
ServerAliveInterval   10
```

Then I got this message while trying to perform a **git clone** command:

```
$ git clone ssh://username_from_openshift@application_name-host_name.rhcloud.com/~/git/application_name.git/ /development/repos/openshift/
Initialized empty Git repository in /development/repos/openshift/.git/
nc: Proxy error: "HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden"
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

if I try connecting directly via **ssh**, I get error messages in a similar fashion.

**Without that config file**:

```
$ ssh username_from_openshift@application_name-host_name.rhcloud.com
ssh: connect to host application_name-host_name.rhcloud.com port 22: Connection refused
```

**With the config file**:

```
$ ssh username_from_openshift@application_name-host_name.rhcloud.com
nc: Proxy error: "HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden"
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

I also tried using **rhc setup (OpenShift client tools** for connecting and it shows the number of gears I have, but it still gives similar error messages.

**Without the config file:**

```
An SSH connection could not be established to application_name-host_name.rhcloud.com. Your
SSH configuration may not be correct, or the application may not be responding.
Connection refused - connect(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
```

**With the config file:**

```
An SSH connection could not be established to application_name-host_name.rhcloud.com. Your
SSH configuration may not be correct, or the application may not be responding.
connection closed by remote host (Net::SSH::Disconnect)
```

Now I also had generated my ssh public key on my machine and pasted it in OpenShift Settings under "Public Keys", so I guess that shouldn't be the problem.

Well? Any ideas and suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Those errors are most likely because the your public ssh key isn't associated to your account properly. Try doing the following

1. Execute `rhc sshkey list` and take note of the output
2. then try adding your pub key buy running `rhc sshkey add <give name for key> ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`